# Adding Custom function to DHTMLX Pivot

Tags: javascript, pivot-table, dhtmlx

I'm using Dhtmlx pivot, and I don't manage to succeed in adding

a custom operation to the Pivot.

the pivot comes with - 4 - builtin operations:

1. Sum
2. Min
3. Max
4. Count

I need a **unique Count** operation, basically like Count, but it

should only count **Distinct values**.

this is what I tried, I added this function to the pivot object:

```
pivot.addMathMethod("uniqueCount", "uniqueCount", (cellData) => {
    if(cellData.length > 0){return (1).toFixed(0) ;}
});
```

you can paste these statements to this [dhtmlx demo](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/pivot/samples/02_configuration/11_footer.html),

I want to get, for example, the number - **4** - in the first Oil

column for the 'Constitutional monarchy' in the pivot, but instead, I

get all - 1 - numbers.

what should I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

try to add some conditions, like this

```
pivot.addMathMethod("uniqueCount", "uniqueCount", (cellData) => {
    if (cellData.length > 0) {
        return cellData.reduce((total, el) => el % 2 === 0 ? total + el : el, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Where `el % 2 === 0` - your's confition